# how to get last id after insert db in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

here I save data to the database with multiple rows, I want to retrieve each last id per row, how do I do that?

ex : print_r result when input data.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => metode 11
            [description] => DESC 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => metode 22
            [description] => DESC 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => metode 33
            [description] => DESC 1
        )
)
```

in database

```
id | name      | description
1    metode 11   desc 1
2    metode 22   desc 2
3    metode 33   desc 3
```

after finished input I want to take each id
and this my code

```
$data = array(); 
$numrow = 1;
foreach ($sheet as $row) {
    if ($numrow > 1) {
        array_push($data, array(
                'name'              => $row['A'],
                'description'       => $row['B'],
        ));
    }
    $numrow++;
}

$this->db->insert_batch('my_tabel', $data);
$myid =$this->db->insert_id();
//after insert i retrieve id using last_id() function, however, only last id is fetched, i want to fetch each id

$data_1 = array();
$numrow2 = 1;

foreach ($sheet as $row) {
    if ($numrow2 > 1) {
        array_push($data_1, array(
            'id_last'  => $myid,
            'id'     => $row['E'],
            'barang' => $row['F'],
        ));
    }
    $numrow2++;
}
```

i want like this :

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [last_id] => 1
                    [id] => 33
                    [barang] => ccc
                )
        
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [last_id] => 2
                    [id] => 44
                    [barang] => dd
                )
        
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [last_id] => 3
                    [id] => 55
                    [barang] => eee
                )
        )
```

thanks in advance for those who have answered
I hope what I said was clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not insert it row by row instead of a batch?
Build a dictionary from each insert to pair it back later on.

```
$data = array(); 
$numrow = 1;
foreach ($sheet as $row) {
    if ($numrow > 1) {
        array_push($data, array(
                'name'              => $row['A'],
                'description'       => $row['B'],
        ));
    }
    $numrow++;
}
$array_of_insert_id = array();

foreach ($data as $index => $data_to_insert) {
    $this->db->insert('my_tabel', $data_to_insert);
    $array_of_insert_id[$index] = $this->db->insert_id();
}

$data_1 = array();
$numrow2 = 1;
$counter = 0;


foreach ($sheet as $row) {
    if ($numrow2 > 1) {
        array_push($data_1, array(
            'id_last'  => $array_of_insert_id[$counter],
            'id'     => $row['E'],
            'barang' => $row['F'],
        ));
    }
    $numrow2++;
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: can you use the variables that I use? I'm confused reading it sorry :D

Comment: @hellows i am, in fact, using variables that you are using. except for the additional array which consists of all the insert_id as well as looping through your $data array to insert into the db instead of inserting the whole batch

Comment: I mean using the full code sorry plis @Patrick Teng

Comment: @hellows like this? only difference was my not including the top part cause it wasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
//table field with input field data array
$table_data = [
   'table_field1' => $input_data1,
   'table_field2' => $input_data2,
];

//insert data in database 
$this->db->insert('table_name',$table_data);

//after insert return id
return $inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```